# How do I center my div as it always shift to the left side of my body

Tags: html, css

**Aim:**
To shift the whole `container/division/div` to the center of my body.

**Problem:**
The container is stuck on the left side of the body after I reduced its width.

I had tried putting `justify-content: center` in the `"big_container"`, but it didn't work

Hope to see some good feedback from dear mentors!

Code snippet:

```css
.main_title {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.big_container {
  width: 500px;
}

.outside {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #3d7bcc, #2fedea);
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  height: 430px;
}

.paragraphs {
  display: flex;
  background-color: black;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container_2 {
  padding: 20px;
}

.text {
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Sony Hedgehog</title>
  <link href="sonic_style.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <h1 class="main_title">Sony the Hedgehog</h1>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="big_container">
    <div class="outside">

      <div class="image_container">
        <!--useless class-->
        <img src="./photo/sonic.jpeg" alt="A photo of sonic">
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="paragraphs">
      <div class="container_2">
        <div class="text_1 text">
          <p><b>Game:</b>Sonic the Hedgehog</p>
        </div>
        <div class="text_2 text">
          <p><b>Year:</b>1991</p>
        </div>
        <div class="text_3 text">
          <p><b>Platform:</b>SEGA</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Which div do you want to center?

Answer (score 2):

You only need to just add `margin-left` and `margin-right` to `auto` in `.big_container` class just like the following.

```
.big_container{
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited my answer, because Vishnu Vinod Answer is best way to do it.

also in future I would suggest you to use & learn Bootstrap it has great documentation and is easy to learn how to use `rows` and `cols` to get wanted effect. It would be really easy to solve this problem with bootstrap

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
<div class="big_container">
    <div class="">
        <div class="outside">

            <div class="image_container">
                <!--useless class-->
                <img src="./photo/sonic.jpeg" alt="A photo of sonic">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="paragraphs">
        <div class="container_2">
            <div class="text_1 text">
                <p><b>Game:</b>Sonic the Hedgehog</p>
            </div>
            <div class="text_2 text">
                <p><b>Year:</b>1991</p>
            </div>
            <div class="text_3 text">
                <p><b>Platform:</b>SEGA</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


</div>






<style>
.main_title{
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 10px;
}
.big_container {
    /* width: 500px; */
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
   max-width: 500px;

}


.outside {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #3d7bcc, #2fedea);
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    height: 430px;
}

.paragraphs {
    display: flex;
    background-color: black;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.container_2 {
    padding: 20px;
}

.text {
    color: white;

}
```